# Can't comment on blog article

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, blog

Tried to comment on [this article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/26/whats-behind-the-hype-about-blazor/) for the first time but it said "Duplicate comment detected; it looks as though you’ve already said that!" (which is a Wordpress message). Why? Is this a bug? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The blog is notoriously *under powered* for its commenting features and I can't suppress the notion this is very much by design. You're not supposed to comment on that blog there or anywhere else for that matter.

Comment: If there's a bug, it's in WordPress, not SE. And blog comments are really too minor to be worth spending dev time on. All in all, if there's corresponding Meta post, comment there, otherwise... no big deal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am assuming that your comment was accidentally double-submitted, and wordpress showd you the duplicate comment message on the second submission.

In any event, your comment did come through and is now [on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/26/whats-behind-the-hype-about-blazor/#comment-628553).

Comment: Thanks. What was strange, I didn't submit twice! Only hit the submit once and got the message. Somehow WP thought it was twice. Strange.